# How to identify the section number of a section header view

Tags: ios, uitableview

There is a button in my header of a `UITableView`. Once the button is touched up inside, how could we know which section does the button belong to? As the tableview is editable, set the tag of the button is not that good when some rows is removed. I have tried using `indexPathForRowAtPoint:` to get the indexPath of the first row belongs to the section, but something weird happened. Is there any better approach?

Edit 1:

Once the tag is used to identify the section number of a header, the tag will not update when the some row has been deleted. Of coz you can reload the tableview to update the tag, but it seems not that good.

For the weird behavior of `indexPathForRowAtPoint:`, I have post another question: [Weird behavior of UITableView method "indexPathForRowAtPoint:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946029/weird-behavior-of-uitableview-method-indexpathforrowatpoint)

Comment: The headerview isn't associated to a section.  Are you referring to a section header?

Comment: Sorry, i mean a section header.

Comment: Not sure why this question is up-voted since it's incomplete.  What about the table being editable makes the tag not work?  What "weird happened" using indexPathForRowAtPoint?  Where's the code for that?  Where's any code for creating the header and the button?

Comment: @danh I post an question to explain the "weird happened" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946029/weird-behavior-of-uitableview-method-indexpathforrowatpoint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above answer seems good enough for me, however, if you don't want to use tags you could create a method that returns the section of a `UITableView` a particular view belongs to, like so:

```
-(int)sectionNumberForView:(UIView*)view inTableView:(UITableView*)tableView {

    int numberOfSections = [tableView numberOfSections];

    int i=0;
    for(; i < numberOfSections; ++i) {
        UIView *headerView = [tableView headerViewForSection:i];
        if (headerView == view) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return i;
}
```

Then inside your Target-Action method and assuming the superview of your button is the section header view:

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender {

    int section = [self sectionNumberForView:sender.superview inTableView:_yourTableView];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I like @LuisCien's answer because the OP wants to avoid tags.  But (a) the answer should show how to get from the button to the section no matter how deeply the button is found in the header view's hierarchy, and (b)the answer supplied conflates section 0 with the case where the header is not found (if the method is passed a view not contained within a header).

```
// LuisCien's good suggestion, with modified test and a NotFound return.

-(NSInteger)sectionNumberForView:(UIView*)view inTableView:(UITableView*)tableView {

    NSInteger numberOfSections = [tableView numberOfSections];

    for(NSInteger i=0; i < numberOfSections; ++i) {
        UIView *headerView = [tableView headerViewForSection:i];
        if ([view isDescendantOfView:headerView]) return i;
    }

    return NSNotFound;
}
```

No need to  call this with the outlet's superview.  Let the descendent check do that work.

```
NSInteger section = [self sectionNumberForView:sender inTableView:_yourTableView];
```

Comment: headerViewForSection: Available in iOS 6.0 and later. Even I test in iOS6, it always return (null)

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946029/weird-behavior-of-uitableview-method-indexpathforrowatpoint

Answer (score 1):

When creating each headerView and adding the UIButton, you could set it's tag to the value of the section, and check for that tag in your action method for the buttons. Something like...

In your creation:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20);
            [button setTag:section];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [view addSubview:button];

    return view;
}
```

Then in your action method:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    int section = sender.tag;

    // Do something based on the section
}
```

Comment: But this code suffers from the problem stated in the question. The table is editable. The section number the header is associated with can change over time as other sections are added or deleted. Using indexPath sections or rows as a tag value only works with tables that have fixed sections and rows.

Comment: I wrote this before his edit, so it would take some additional work to get this going