# Weird behavior of UITableView method "indexPathForRowAtPoint:"

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

As show in the following code, when the tableview is stretched (never scrolled up), the `NSLog(@"tap is not on the tableview cell")` will always be called (**as i thought the indexPath will always be nil**). But when i tap the avatar in the section header with section number greater than 2, the `NSLog` does not get called. It is weird, anyone know what's going on here?

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 ...
     UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
     tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
     [avatar addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
     //avatar is UIImageView and the user interaction is enabled.
     [headerView addSubview: aMessageAvatar];
     return headerView;
 ...

}


-(void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
    if (!indexPath) {
    NSLog(@"tap is not on the tableview cell");
    }
}
```

Comment: When you click on that subsequent header, you say that `indexPath` is not `nil`. So, what is it? As an aside, what is `heightForHeaderInSection:` returning? And what is the height of your `avatar`? If your If your header view is not set to clip subviews, I could easily imagine that you think you're tapping on the header view, but that point could correspond to a cell behind it.

Comment: @Rob It is the indexPath of the row under the header. The height of the header is 48.0f and the frame of avatar is (8, 8, 32,32).

Comment: That's curious, but again, I'm not sure I'd worry too much about it. It might be some idiosyncrasy (i.e. bug) in `indexPathForRowAtPoint` not gracefully handling someone tapping in the section headers/footers. It doesn't seem like a terribly important issue, because `indexPathForRowAtPoint` is obviously not the right solution for your problem. Why worry about a potential bug in a solution you know is the wrong solution? Using `tag` is the logical solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tap location is the location in the header, not a cell, so it would never match a cell `indexPath`.

You could probably set the `tag` for the `avatar` view to be the section number in `viewForHeaderInSection` and then retrieve the section number in `handleTapGesture` via `sender.view.tag`. For example:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 ...
     UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
     tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
     avatar.tag = section;                // save the section number in the tag
     avatar.userInteractionEnabled = YES; // and make sure to enable touches
     [avatar addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
     //avatar is UIImageView and the user interaction is enabled.
     [headerView addSubview: aMessageAvatar];
     return headerView;
 ...

}

-(void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSInteger section = sender.view.tag;
    NSLog(@"In section %d", section);
}
```

Comment: Yes, as i thought the indexPath will always be nil, but when I touch the header after 2nd the indexPath has an value.

Comment: @luyuan I find that very surprising. But clearly it doesn't make sense to set a tap gesture on something that is not a cell and then using the resulting gesture handler to figure which cell you tapped. If you're looking for the section you tapped on, you can use the `tag` approach. Otherwise you'll have to describe what you're trying to do, because the original notion doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: @Rob Plz check the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945661/how-to-identify-the-section-number-of-a-section-header-view

Comment: @luyuan Ok. Pursuant to your other question, in which you seem to be concerned about users deleting rows. If you're letting users add/remove rows/sections, maybe the `tag` shouldn't a zero-based section number index. It should be some unique numeric identifier you assign. But the root of the solution is the same; use the `tag` to keep track of which header you tapped on, making sure that the `tag` uniquely identifies the header in question.