# Can't get indexPath of cell in header

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have created prototype custom header cell for a tableView with a button on it. I am trying to get the indexPath of the cell when the button is tapped, but I don't receive it. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

```
 protocol MediaHeaderCellDelegate: class {
  func editPost(cell: MediaHeaderCell)
}

  class MediaHeaderCell: UITableViewCell {

   weak var delegate: MediaHeaderCellDelegate?
    @IBAction func moreOptionsAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
     delegate?.editPost(cell: self)
   }
}


      class NewsfeedTableViewController:UITableViewController,  MediaHeaderCellDelegate {

  func editPost(cell: MediaHeaderCell) {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
        print("indexpath could not be given")
        return}
   }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.mediaHeaderCell) as! MediaHeaderCell
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.media = media[section]
    return cell
   }

         override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.mediaCell, for: indexPath) as! MediaTableViewCell

    cell.currentUser = currentUser
    cell.media = media[indexPath.section]
    cell.delegate = self        
    return cell
     }

}
```

[image]

Comment: What actually happens when you tap a button in a cell? Is the cell's `moreOptionsAction` being called? Is the `editPost` being called in your view controller?

Comment: Yes, both `moreOptionsAction` and `editPost` are being called, but in `editPost(cell: MediaHeaderCell)` else statement is evaluated.

Comment: Any reason, why you are not using `cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` (instead of `viewForHeaderInSection`) ?

Comment: That's the problem. Do not use a table cell for a section header. Use `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. And never call `dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: @rmaddy Could you put it in an answer. I think other users will find it useful since I found this implementation `viewForHeaderInSection ` in a paid course. Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23846985/341994

Comment: @rmaddy  what I did was to create two prototype with two classes for each to manage their content. The goal was to have a header at the top of each section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate issue is that you are using a table cell as a section header view. That should not be done. Once you resolve that, your next task is to determine the table section from the header view whose button was tapped.

First, change your `MediaHeaderCell` to be a header view that extends `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and update your protocol accordingly:

```
protocol MediaHeaderViewDelegate: class {
    func editPost(view: MediaHeaderView)
}

class MediaHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    weak var delegate: MediaHeaderViewDelegate?

    @IBAction func moreOptionsAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.editPost(cell: self)
    }
}
```

Then you need to register the header view in your view controller.

Then update your `viewForHeaderInSection`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: Storyboard.mediaHeaderView) as! MediaHeaderView
    view.delegate = self
    view.media = media[section]
    view.tag = section

    return view
}
```

And last, update your protocol method implementation:

```
func editPost(view: MediaHeaderView) {
    let section = view.tag
    // do something
}
```

There is one possible issue with this. If your table allows sections to be added or removed, then it is possible that a header view's tag could be wrong when the button is tapped.

Comment: The user will have the possibility to delete a post, so the tag could cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @bibscy But that would be a row, not a whole section.

Comment: The documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614975-dequeuereusableheaderfooterview states for the return value of `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier:)`: "or nil if no such object exists in the reusable view queue.". Is this outdated? because you are not testing for nil...

Answer (score 2):

So this is actually all about learning what section a section header belongs to?? Here’s what I do. I have a header class:

```
class MyHeaderView : UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    var section = 0
}
```

I register it:

```
self.tableView.register(
        MyHeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: self.headerID)
```

I use and configure it:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let h = tableView
        .dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: self.headerID) as! MyHeaderView
    // other stuff 
    h.section = section // *
    return h
}
```

Now if the header view is tappable or contains a button or whatever, learning what section this is the header of is trivial.

Comment: This suffers from the same potential issue of using the header view's tag as shown in my answer. Using the `tag` or your own `section` property is basically the same thing.

Comment: @rmaddy sure, it was idiotic of Apple to leave out this key bit of functionality.

Comment: Yeah, `UITableView` needs a `section(for headerFooterView:)` method similar to `indexPath(for cell:)`.

Comment: @rmaddy totally