# How to get the updated section of a section footer view in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Sorry for a weird title, I don't know how to best describe this question with a single line. Here's the situation:

1. I have a UITableView, for each section in the UITableView, I also have a custom section footer, which contains a UIButton
2. The button has a target function, which needs to access the section where it belongs to.

I don't have any problems so far:

```
func viewForFooterInSection() -> UIView? {
    let footer = tableView.deququeReusableHeaderFooterView(....)

    footer.button.tag = section
    footer.button.addTarget(...)

    return footer
}

@objc private func onPressButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let section: Int = sender.tag

    // Do things with the section
}
```

However, users can delete/insert sections, in which case, the tags of the buttons are not updated. For example, at this moment, the first button has tag 0, but when I insert a new section at position 0, that button's tag should no longer be 0, it should be 1.

I have thought about updating all visible sections' footer view, but I wonder if there's a cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945661/how-to-identify-the-section-number-of-a-section-header-view for an answer in Objective-C. Should be easy enough to translate to Swift.

Comment: @rmaddy, thank you, this question solves my problem 100%.